# Rxjs/Angular 4- using publishReplay() on Auth status checking makes my app unresponsive if I enter an AuthGuarded URL on the address bar

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, http-caching, angular2-observables

first of all, my app without the publishReplay() is working fine now but I want to optimize the requests by using some kind of caching to avoid going to the backend everytime to check if the user is logged in.  I have the following context. I have auth aware components that need to be hidden or shown depending on the user being logged in or not. I have

a)an **AuthGuard** to guard for certain routes, it redirects the user to sign in route if the user is not logged in:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
     return this.authService.isAuthenticated().map(isAuth => {
       console.log('is authenticated',isAuth);
            if (isAuth) {
                return true;
            }else{
                this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
                return false;
            }
        });
  }
}
```

b) an **AuthService** with the method isAuthenticated to check with the backend if the user is logged in(I'm using conventional sessions stored on a db). Here at the end of the chain im using publishReplay(3) cause I have 3 components that are auth aware at loading time. Note that if I remove that method everything works just fine and the authguard does its job, if I add it then I go to for examples localhost:4200/dashboard and the app freezes, links doesn't work and auth guard code is not getting to get executed since I put a console.log 'is authenticated' (as shown above) on AuthGuard and it's not showing on the console, giving the idea that the execution never gets there. If I remove publishReplay then I see the message again on the console:

isAuthenticated(): Observable {

```
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.getHeaders(), withCredentials: true });
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/addsfiliates/sponsor/check/login',options)
    .map(response => {
      let res = response.json();
      console.log("response");
      if (res.code == 200) {
        this.userIsAuthenticated.next(true);
        return true;
      }
    }
  ).catch((err)=>{
    //maybe add in the future if the code is 403 then send him to login otherwise send him elsewhere
    return Observable.of(false);
  }).publishReplay(3);
```

}

c)A route file guarding the routes, just for context explaining:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch:'full'},
  { path: '', component: MainComponent },
  { path: 'signin', component:SigninComponent},
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate:[AuthGuard],component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo:'dashboard/overview', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'overview', component: OverviewCampaignsComponent },
      { path: 'active', component: ActiveCampaignsComponent},
      { path: 'history', component: HistoryCampaignsComponent}
    ] }

]
```

Am I taking the right approach here to do the caching for the auth aware components? If I am, how can I use this publish replay method to make it work with my use case? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publishReplay` returns `ConnectableObservable` you need to call `connect` on it then it will connect to the source observable:

```
let obs = this.http.get(...)
    .publishReplay(1);
obs.connect;
return obs;
```

This should fix your app but you will not accomplish what you want. Because on each call you still create a new observable and thus make a call to the server.

The simpliest straightforward solution is:

```
export class AuthService {
    private isAuthenticatedValue: boolean;

    isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
        if(this.isAuthenticatedValue != null) {
            return Observable.of(this.isAuthenticatedValue);
        }

        return this.http.get(...)
            ...
            .do(flag => {
                this.isAuthenticatedValue = flag;
            })
    }
}
```

Additionaly you should clear cached value periodically because session can expire on the server. You can do it by clearing the value with `setTimeout`.

Comment: I used to have it like your 2nd approach but I didn't know what should I do for this.isAuthenticatedValue to become false  and when to do it, cause if the user authenticates it will never go to the backend cause that variable will be always true, now that you added the 'clear value factor it makes sense' . Where should I set the value to false again?? which is the recommended time to make it expire? could you provide a simple gist if it's not too much trouble? And what about that .do method?? it's the first time I see it...

Comment: another thing, what happens if the session expires in the server and that variable is set to true..that would give an forbidden code for every request....how would you handle that? I'm quite lost regarding this

Comment: @Juan, OK, let me think. Your original intent was to reduce number of requests. But why are doing this requests at all? You want to ensure that only logged in users have access to some components. But what happens when session expires after component is opened? All actions will result in 401?

Comment: @Juan If this is the case then IMHO the best way is to handle 401 globally. After login we treat user as a logged in until otherwise proven (server returns 401). I can create a simple app with this approach if it suits you (not sooner than tomorrow).

Comment: I did it that way in the end, thank you very much!!!, I didn't used the timeout, I just used the 'logged in until proved wrong'. I jsut make a dummy request at the beggining of the app on the constructor of the authService, set the variable and then on every request I just catch the errors and if there's any Forbidden http response I just set the variable isAuthenticated on the authService to false...it works wonders at the cost of 1 request at the beggining....thank you very much, case closed!! xD